# MYSQL - server quits midway through a script

Tags: python, mysql

I am using mysqldb/python to push some data into a mysql db.

The script parses a bunch of XML files for the data.

The MySQL server seems to quit and give me a '#2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)' error midway through the transactions - in a different place every time I run it (so I am assuming its not a specific piece of data that is making it fall over...)

It works perfectly until it reaches ~12 or 13 file and it gives me this error:

```
Error 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10055)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sigFileParser.py", line 113, in <module>
 doParser(sigfile_filename)
File "sigFileParser.py", line 106, in
 doParser
  doFormatsPush(packedFormats)
File "sigFileParser.py", line 27, in
 doFormatsPush
sys.exit (1)
NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined
```

Once the error occurs I can not get into MySQL console or via PHOPmyadmin

If I leave if for a while, I can get back into MySQL

MySQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS patterns
 (Version int(3),
 DateCreated DATETIME,
 SigID int(4),
 SigSpecificity CHAR(10),
 ByteSeqReference CHAR(12),
 MinFragLength int(4),
 Position int(4),
 SubSeqMaxOffset int(4),
 SubSeqMinOffset int(4),
 Pattern TEXT)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS formats
(Version int(3),
DateCreated DATETIME,
FormatID int(4),
FormatName TEXT,
PUID TEXT,
FormatVersion TEXT,
FormatMIMEType TEXT,
InternalSignatureID int(4),
Extension TEXT,
HasPriorityOverFileFormatID int(4))
```

Py code

```
from lxml import etree
import re, os, MySQLdb
def doPatternPush(packedPatterns):
 try:
  db = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "", db = "sigfiles")
  c = db.cursor()
  c.execute('''INSERT INTO sigfiles.patterns
  (Version,DateCreated,SigID,SigSpecificity,ByteSeqReference,MinFragLength,Position,SubSeqMaxOffset,SubSeqMinOffset,Pattern)
   VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''', packedPatterns)
  db.commit()
  except MySQLdb.Error, e:
  print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
  sys.exit (1)
 return (db)
def doFormatsPush(packedFormats):
 try:
  db = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "", db = "sigfiles")
  c = db.cursor()
  c.execute('''INSERT INTO sigfiles.formats
  (Version,DateCreated,FormatID,FormatName,PUID,FormatVersion,FormatMIMEType,InternalSignatureID,Extension,HasPriorityOverFileFormatID)
  VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''', packedFormats)
  db.commit()
 except MySQLdb.Error, e:
  print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
  sys.exit (1)
 return(db)
def doParser(sigfile_filename):
 tree = etree.parse(sigfile_filename) 
 root = tree.getroot()
 attributes = root.attrib
 if 'DateCreated' in root.attrib:
  DateCreated = (attributes["DateCreated"])
 if 'Version' in root.attrib:
  Version = (attributes["Version"])
 ##--------- get internal sig details ------------------
 for a in range (len(root[0])):  #loops for sig ID
  attributes = root[0][a].attrib
  SigID=(attributes["ID"])
  SigSpecificity = (attributes["Specificity"])
  for b in range (len(root[0][a])):  # loops for sequence pattern inside each sig
   attributes = root[0][a][b].attrib
   if 'Reference' in root[0][a][b].attrib: 
    ByteSeqReference = (attributes["Reference"])
   else:
    ByteSeqReference = "NULL"  
   attributes = root[0][a][b][0].attrib
   if 'MinFragLength' in root[0][a][b][0].attrib:
    MinFragLength=(attributes["MinFragLength"])
   else: 
    MinFragLength=''
   if 'Position' in root[0][a].attrib:
    Position=(attributes["Position"])
   else:
    Position=''
   if 'SubSeqMaxOffset' in root[0][a][b][0].attrib:
    SubSeqMaxOffset=(attributes["SubSeqMaxOffset"])
   else:
    SubSeqMaxOffsee = ''  
   if 'SubSeqMinOffset' in root[0][a][b][0].attrib:
    SubSeqMinOffset=(attributes["SubSeqMinOffset"])
   else:
    SubSeqMinOffset = ''     
   Pattern = root[0][a][b][0][0].text
   packedPatterns =     [Version,DateCreated,SigID,SigSpecificity,ByteSeqReference,MinFragLength,Position,SubSeqMaxOffset,SubSeqMinOffset,Pattern]
   doPatternPush(packedPatterns)
##-------- get format ID details-------------
 for a in range (len(root[1])):
  attributes = root[1][a].attrib
  if 'ID' in root[1][a].attrib:
   FormatID = (attributes['ID'])
  else:
   FormatID = "NULL" 
  if 'Name' in root[1][a].attrib:
   FormatName = (attributes['Name'])
  else:
   FormatName = "NULL" 
  if 'PUID' in root[1][a].attrib:
   PUID = (attributes['PUID'])
  else:
   PUID = "NULL" 
  if 'Version' in root[1][a].attrib:
   FormatVersion = (attributes['Version'])
  else:
   FormatVersion = "NULL" 
  if 'MIMEType' in root[1][a].attrib:
   FormatMIMEType = (attributes['MIMEType'])
  else:
   FormatMIMEType = "NULL"  
  InternalSignatureID,Extension,HasPriorityOverFileFormatID = ('', 'NULL', '') 
  for b in range (len(root[1][a])): #extracts the tags for each format ID
   tagType = root[1][a][b].tag
   tagText = root[1][a][b].text
   tagType = re.sub('{http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/pronom/SignatureFile}', '', tagType)
   if tagType == 'InternalSignatureID':
    InternalSignatureID = tagText
   elif tagType == 'Extension':
    Extension = tagText
    HasPriorityOverFileFormatID = ''
   else:
    HasPriorityOverFileFormatID = tagText
    Extension = 'NULL' 
   packedFormats = [Version,DateCreated,FormatID,FormatName,PUID,FormatVersion,FormatMIMEType,InternalSignatureID,Extension,HasPriorityOverFileFormatID]
   doFormatsPush(packedFormats)
 if __name__ == "__main__":
 path = "C:\Users\NDHA\Desktop\droid sigs all"
 for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
  for file in files:
   sigfile_filename = str(path)+"\\"+str(file)
   doParser(sigfile_filename) 
   print sigfile_filename
 db.close()
```

All the XML comes from here: http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/aboutapps/pronom/droid-signature-files.htm

Answer (score 1):

The error you get tells you exactly what's wrong

```
NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined
```

You don't `import sys` in your python file.

As for the db connection, if your socket is not placed in `/tmp/mysql.sock`, you can specify where to look for it when you try to connect to the db using the `unix_socket` parameter.

Try:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect (unix_socket = 'path_to_sock', host = "localhost", 
                      user = "root", passwd = "", db = "sigfiles")
```

Where you replace 'path_to_sock' with the actual path to the mysql sock.

Other stuff you should check in case that isn't the issue:

- Check to make sure the username/password combination is correct
- Try stopping and re-starting the mysqld service
- Check the error log files for more specific errors

Comment: I have imported sys, and the issue persists, thanks for looking though!

Comment: How do I know what my definitive mysql sock is?

Comment: You could try to find the file on your system. Assuming your working with a linux based system, this can be done using the `find` command in the terminal

Comment: OK Thanks, I'm going to head home shortly, so I'll try it on another machine and see if its a local issue on this machine! :) thanks for your help.

Comment: I ran the code, as is, on another machine, and it ran perfectly. Both machines had a fresh install of WAMP, both are 64bit running Win7 and python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

This is your first error:

> Error 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10055)

It seems you disconnect from MySQL at some point. Check your code and see if you're explicitly or implicitly getting disconnected from the server and also check if your MySQL server is still listening to connections... maybe you're killing the server from outside your app... who knows? :)

Comment: Yupe, I can see that the mysql server is dying, but I'm not sure why... when it fails it locks out for a few mins, and knocks out the whole netwrk connection (based on the browser not responding to new page requests - it doesn't timeout, it simply doesn't respond). Nothing is getting written to the mysql.log

Comment: Hmm, that's quite a weird behaviour. I don't think MySQL is knocking out the whole network. Something else is going on with your computer... malware maybe?